# How to ignore \n for istream strings

Tags: c++, string, output, istream

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can ignore the "\n" coming in from istream?  I'm trying to extract data from txt file where in some "cells", text has been written in such that there are "\n" coming in from when the user pressed Enter.

My goal is to take in some parts of this text and output it with " ; " separating the parts.  However, in doing so, sometimes a "\n" gets sucked in and the output cell starts continuing downwards instead of just line going from right to left (which is preferred).

Any advice would be much appreciated!

```
string vectorToString(vector<size_t> positionVector, string mainString,
                                      string outputString, int numLetters)

{
    //Check how many different positions were found and make that the length
    //of the vector that will store all the strings for each finding
    int positionVectorLength = positionVector.size();
    //foundPos is the position of the cursor along the foundPositions vector
    int vectorPosition=0;
    while (vectorPosition < positionVectorLength)
    {
        //define local variable that will store the value along the vector
        size_t vectorPositionValue = positionVector.at(vectorPosition);


        //append the numLetters after the positionValue in string frameNum
        outputString.append(mainString, vectorPositionValue, numLetters);
        outputString.append(" ; ");     

        //reiterate until all the positions have been recorded
        vectorPosition+=1;
    }

    //return the string of frame numbers
    return(outputString);
}
```

Comment: you should use const & and & for your function arguments. And can't you just remove all occurances of '\n' in you input string using string::find and string::erase?

Comment: @UldisK why do you say that?

Comment: You mentioned that the user types in enter and this gets sucked in. Perhaps it is as easy as using istream::getline()?
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/
Its default delim is '\n' and it discards it.

Comment: you are copying large collection values that are not modified.. you should pass them as "const &" ..

Comment: To add to what UldisK is saying. You are passing the 'positionVector' variable by value, meaning you are making a copy of that whole vector every time you call this function. That is a lot of overhead. If you pass by const& you will pass by reference (saving the copy) and the const guarantees no modification to the data will happen (just like copying it guarantees no modification).

Comment: I don't see any use of `istream` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to remove all the `\n` from your string:

```
mainString.erase(std::remove(mainString.begin(),mainString.end(),'\n'),mainString.end());
```

Comment: But it's better not to have them in the first place.

Comment: Yes but "I'm trying to extract data from txt file", they are already there, so at one point OP is going to have to remove them. Not reading them is better though, I agree.

Comment: No, many methods of reading from a file skip the newlines. :)

Comment: I didn't say you could not, I just provided a way to remove the characters from a string, in case he/she cannot change how the file is read.

Comment: No need to get defensive; I was just saying.